# How do I apply a patch to my Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, kernel, patch

I am trying to compile the iscsi-target software SCST. It wants me to apply a patch to my Linux kernel in order to allow for certain performance gains. The problem is I still new to Linux development. Where do I begin? How do I apply the patch? Do I need to recompile the kernel? Help!

I am running Ubuntu 10.04.3 amd64

Kernel version 2.6.32-28-server

Comment: Yes, you'll need to compile - a patch is a modification of source code, not the binary. How you apply the patch should be in their README (or INSTALL, if they have it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Linux distribution usually has its own instructions. Search their website or ask on IRC – or at least tell us the distro; without knowing it, it's impossible to provide a reliable anwer.

- Arch Linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels#Compilation
- CentOS: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel
- Debian: http://users.wowway.com/~zlinuxman/Kernel.htm, http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.kernel-compilation.html, https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/ch08s06.html.en
- Fedora: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel
- Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

---

The generic instructions are:

1. Download the kernel source from [Kernel.org](http://kernel.org/). "Stable" is probably the best choice. Extract to a convenient place (I use `~/src/linux`).

   - **Read the file named `README`.**
2. Once inside the source directory, copy the current kernel's configuration, with:
   `zcat /proc/config.gz > .config`

   If /proc doesn't have it, look for `/boot/config-[version]` instead.
3. Apply the patch, with:
   `patch -p1 < foo.patch` (try `-p0` if it gets rejected).
4. Compile the kernel with:
   `make silentoldconfig`
   `make`
5. Install the modules with:
   `sudo make modules_install`
6. Install the kernel image `.../linux/arch/i386/boot/bzImage` to wherever your bootloader wants it. (For example, `/boot/vmlinuz-custom`.)
7. Build an initramfs for the new kernel, if your distribution uses it, and again make sure the bootloader knows its location. For example, on Arch Linux you would use:
   `mkinitcpio -k /boot/vmlinuz-custom -g /boot/initramfs-custom`

Comment: Oops silly me I forgot that part. I running on Ubuntu 10.04.3 amd64. My kernel is 2.6.32-28-server.

Comment: @Solignis: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: Well so far everything is compiling,....taking a long time though. Thanks for the help.